# DataTables (server-side scripting) pagination alignment goes off

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery data-tables plugin for my tables(using server-side scripting. but the alignment of pagination of data tables is going off after 6th page, please help me to sort this out.

pagination before 6th page:

[image]

pagination after 6th page:

[image]

```
$('#contacts').DataTable(
            {
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "pageLength": 1,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "ajax":{
                 url:"abc.php",
                    type:"post"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                            {"className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all"}
                          ]
        } );

        $('input[type=search]').addClass('form-control round');
        $("#contacts_filter").css('margin-right', '15px');
        $("#contacts_filter").css('text-align', 'center');
        $("#contacts_info").css('padding-left', '15px');
        $("#contacts_info").css('font-size', '20px');
        $("#contacts_paginate").css('padding-bottom', '10px');
        $("#contacts_paginate").css('padding-top', '10px');
```

Comment: Whenever possible, embed image in question so readers are not inconvenienced. I tried to fix your question but got error the image format is not compatible.